# Tried detecting a self created DeadLock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I wrote the below Java code for creating the Deadlock, I passed a resource String variable to the threads and locked it using **synchronized** block and put up an infinite loop inside that so that first thread will never ever leave it, so the second thread will not be able to access it forever.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String resourcs = "testResource";
        MainClass M = new MainClass();
        Thread firstThread = new Thread(M.new MyThread("First",resourcs));
        Thread seconThread =  new Thread(M.new MyThread("Second",resourcs));
        firstThread.start();
        seconThread.start();

    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable{
        String resource;
        String name;
        public MyThread(String name,String resource) {
            this.resource = resource;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (resource) {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Still working on the thread :"+name);

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then in the other window, I wrote the code for detecting the Deadlock like below,

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory; 
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class DetectDeadLock {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
        long[] threadIds = bean.findDeadlockedThreads();

        if (threadIds != null) {
            ThreadInfo[] infos = bean.getThreadInfo(threadIds);

            for (ThreadInfo info : infos) {
                StackTraceElement[] stack = info.getStackTrace();
                System.out.println("here");
                // Log or store stack trace information.
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But the Watch Dog detected nothing.

---

1. **Have I created the dead lock correctly?** (I think yes, because the console is only printing the first thread's code)
2. **Do i have to wait for some time** (idk how much) for the 'Watch Dog' code to detect the Deadlock?

Comment: This is not a Deadlock-situation because the first Thread can work totally fine. You need to create a situation where the second Thread waits for a resource of the first Thread and the first Thread waits for a resource of the second Thread.

Comment: The correct word for the situation you've created is "starvation." Yours is a trivial example of it. In general, a thread is starved if one or more other threads always have some resource locked every time (or almost every time) the starved thread tries to use it. In your example, the "every time" also happens to be the one-and-only time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get a deadlock is out of order synchronizations. This example deadlocks two threads and then uses the above checker to find them. It can all be run from a main method.

```
    final Object a = new Object();
    final Object b = new Object();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
    
    new Thread(()->{
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " running");
        synchronized(a){    
            try{
                latch.countDown();
                latch.await();
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                return;
            }
            synchronized(b){
                System.out.println("no deadlock");  
            }
        }   
        
    }).start();

    
    new Thread(()->{
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " running");
        synchronized(b){
            try{
                latch.countDown();
                latch.await();
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                return;
            }
            synchronized(a){
                System.out.println("no deadlock");  
            }
        }   
        
    }).start();
```

By adding a small delay, I can find two deadlocked thread id's.

```
    Thread.sleep(100);
    ThreadMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long[] threadIds = bean.findDeadlockedThreads();
    for(long id: threadIds){
        System.out.println(id + " deadlocked");
    }
```

Then the output looks like:

> 18 running
>
> 19 running
>
> 19 deadlocked
>
> 18 deadlocked

The `Thread.sleep` can be omitted, but then there is a race condition. Possibly `bean.findDeadlockedThreads();` could happen before there is a deadlock. Even with the sleep there is a race condition, but it is incredibly rare. The latch could make it a guarantee.

The CountDownLatch can be removed, but then the threads will only deadlock sometimes. Othertimes, one thread will finish before the other thread starts.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Naaa, it didn't, Do i have to wait for sometime?

Comment: @nobalG if you check for a deadlock before the threads have actually deadlocked then it wouldn't show up. It should be pretty quick though.

Comment: @nobalG I edited it to include the check, and it says I have two deadlocked threads.

Comment: @nobalG note that this is for the same process, if you want to check for tasks on a different process you have to connect to that process.

Comment: Yea, this code works fine, I have a doubt, the code that checks for the deadlocks must be the part of the parent thread? Is it so? Firstly i created two separate programs, one for creating deadlock and the other for checking the deadlock. They were completely separate.

Comment: @nobalG It doesn't have to do with being the parent thread, it has to do with the process. If you start one process, and then the other process starts, how will the second process know which process to check for jvm/deadlocks/etc. This can definitely be done with JMX though, where you attach to a remote jvm.

Comment: Yea, Thats convincing... Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no deadlock in your code. Deadlock happens when two (or more) threads wait for each other. This is not the case here. One thread waits, the other is active (in an endless loop, but that doesn't mean it's deadlocked.)

Comment: OK, thanks, but do i need to wait for sometime after creating the deadlock ?

Comment: It's unusual, but theoretically possible to have more than two threads participating:  A waits for B, B waits for C, C waits ... for Z, and Z waits for A.